# Endpoint for getting STORE_UUID and ITEM_UUID on Uber Eats

Tags: uber-api

Is there any **Uber Eats API** where I can get the store UUID and the item UUID once I pass the exact name of the item and the exact name of the place?

My requirement is to get those to create the URL scheme [1] to open up the Uber Eats app from my app.

[1] ubereats://store/browse?client_id=eats&storeUUID={STORE_UUID}&itemUUID={ITEM_UUID}